# Are any of the questions in Rendezvous with Rama answered in the sequels

Tags: arthur-c-clarke, rendezvous-with-rama, rama-revealed

Whilst not asking for spoilers, are the Rama sequels worth reading for answers to the questions posed in the original?

In particular is the nature and purpose of the unseen aliens explained?

Comment: I did start the first sequel, but the horrible writing (never Clarke's strong point) rather discouraged me.

Comment: @Horner:  I don't think that was Clarke's writing that got you.  The first sequel had writing mistakes that no seasoned science fiction writer would make.

Comment: Having read all four -- yes, but they're better left unanswered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *In particular the nature and purpose of the unseen aliens?*

Those aliens get explained in Rama Revealed (the 4th book in the series).

Answer (score 3):

The Rama sequels are very different from the original book's vector.  Rama serves as a background, but the main scope is about the human race ways of **society**. If you're interested in that as a topic, they are well worth reading.